# o terminal nao reconhece o nome mongo

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, tabela-banco-de-dados, mongoose, mongodb-csharp

eu instalei o mongodb, cuando coloco o nome mongod no terminal ele icia certinho mais cuando coloco o nome mongo aparece esto.
C:\Users\Usuário>mongo
'mongo' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Isso acontece porque os binários do MongoDB não foram adicionados no `PATH`. Por padrão os binário ficam em `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin`.